# how to search character plus using pandas.Series.str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

How do I search the character '+' using "pandas.Series.str.contains" in a pandas dataframe column. I tried

```
df_noplus = df[df['column1'].str.contains('+',case=False)]
```

It gave me an error

```
  File "/home/anil/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py", line 638, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
```

error: nothing to repeat

Comment: does `df_noplus = df[df['column1'].str.contains('\+',case=False)]` work?

Comment: Yes , put a slash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use backslash berofe plus:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['+1','+2','-4']})

df['a'].str.contains('\+')
```

result:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```